# Paramiko SFTP Client creates zero sized file after throwing IOError

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

Hi I am  trying to copy a remote file in a server to a local location using Paramiko's SFTP client. Here below is the code.

```
    try:
        self.SFTP.get(remotepath, localpath, callback=None)
    except IOError as e:
        print "File Not Found  "+self.location
```

Remote location doesn't always contains the file requested so I want to print the Error message and end the process.

Unfortunately it prints the message(IOError message) but it also creates the local file with zero size.

Is this a bug or is there any other way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected.

Instead trying to get a file that you don't know if it exist, I suggest you either:

- first try to find it using the Paramiko SFTP `listdir` command, or
- try to get an SFTPFile object from it using Paramiko SFTP `file` command.

  - If it fails, the file doesn't exist.
  - If it succeeds, just `close` the SFTPFile object, and download the file with the `get` command.

Comment: Currently what I am doing is removing the file using `os.remove(localpath)` after the exception is thrown. I am looking for a way to eliminate the file creation through the SFTP client. and thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome. (may I suggest that you up-vote the answer?)

Answer (score 2):

I would use:
`sftp.stat(remotepath)`

So, in your sample code:

```
try:
    if self.SFTP.stat(remotepath):
        self.SFTP.get(remotepath, localpath, callback=None)
except IOError as e:
    print "File Not Found  "+self.location
```

[SFTP - Paramiko documentation](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html)

Comment: stat() will raise FileNotFoundError if not found, so the if statement is not useful.